# Why I am getting None when I parser a jason string in Spark(scala) from URL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a Jason object from URL and trying to parser, when I do it it is returning None, Can someone please help me here.

```
URL DATA: col = """{"column1":"1","column2":"2"}"""
```

Logic:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON._
for (line <- Source.fromURL("/u/r/l").getLines) {
try {
val xrp=line.split("=")(1)
val head = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(xrp)
    } catch {
        case e: Exception => None
    }     
}
```

When I try and assign by copy and paste manually, getting what i expected

```
al someval = """{"column1":"1","column2":"2"}"""
someval: String = {"column1":"1","column2":"2"}
val head = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(someval)
head: Option[Any] = Some(Map(column1 -> 1, column2 -> 2))
```

But I was failing and reading from URL dir.Can someone please help here?

Comment: Maybe your URL is wrong, but I don't think there's enough info for us to reproduce your problem here. You can start by getting rid of the try/catch, as that seems to be swallowing the exception. Side note: I don't think you're using None correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's  because you include triple quotes on both sides.

Try

```
scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(xrp.trim.drop(3).dropRight(3))
```

Or

```
val pattern = "(\\{.*\\})".r

pattern.findFirstIn(xrp).flatMap(s => scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(s))
```